How do I calculate how to change the cut off frequencies of this bandpass filter?
I am trying to find the transfer function of this filter to change the cut off frequencies later.
When I do the calculations the traditional way the equation is very long and messy.
Maybe there is something I am missing?
I found that this filter is called a "K-constant filter", but K-constant filters are usually as I understood either "pi-type" or "T-type", and the filter I have is a mix of the two.
I would appreciate any advice on how to find the transfer function of the filter.
The port impedances are 50 ohms.


Just use FACTS ...

Please correct your schematic as per the replies you are giving in comments @sozzzani

This is a homework problem

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

In general such a filter circuit can be roughly understood by looking at the component values, but  to find the transfer you will indeed have to use equations, or leave that job to a circuit simulator (or use the equations with some programming language).
To just understand what happens, note that the components seem to be used in pairs to create resonators. For instance LC-series pairs going from left to right, like C1+L1, and C2+L2, are creating low-impedance to let signals through in the pass band. Likewise, the LC-series pairs going to ground, like L6+C7 are meant to short certain frequencies to ground, usually to block signals just outside the pass band. Finally you have the parallel pairs going to ground, like C4//L4 and C5//L5, meant to have high impedance in the pass band but low impedance outside it, good for shorting farther out-of-band signals to ground.
This makes it possible to judge where in the frequency band the components have most influence, but since they all influence each other this remains an inaccurate process.
To do it correctly, for a given frequency f, you could first compute the complex impedances of all those pairs, and then use them in a simpler ladder network for which the equation is relatively easy to write down. But perhaps this is already what you have done...

I calculated the resonant frequencies of each pair and they are all around (8-10)MHz, but the cut-off frequencies are 3MHz and 30MHz. (8-10)MHz is right in the middle of 3MHz and 30MHz on logarithmic scale.
I changed the resonant frequencies of all the pairs to (4-6)MHz, and pass has “shifted to the left” by one logarithmic scale. Now the cut-off frequencies are 2MHz and 20 MHz. 5 MHz is again right in the middle of the both.
So if the resonant frequencies of all the Filters are roughly (8-10)MHz, then why did connecting all these LC pairs make the band-width wider/flatter?

Good question! Already in the early days of radio people found that with "critical coupling", two identical resonators create a broadened bandpass filter with an approximately flat top:
https://www.worldradiohistory.com/BOOKSHELF-ARH/Technology/Author-Groups/Rufus-Turner/LC-Circuits-Rufus-Turner.pdf#page=25
Or: https://brats-qth.org/training/advanced/trandrec14.htm
There must be lots of references about this...
NB: it only happens when they influence each other sufficiently, with weak coupling you just get more peaking and effectively a narrower filter.

Wow this is so helpful, thank you for the links very much!

The dominant component values seem to point to the 10MHz region. Pass band seems quite wide (from about 2 MHz up to 36 MHz). The basic form of constant-k filter is PI-type rather than T-type, but as OP suggests, it seems to be something in between, due to L1.
I confess to approach these with heuristic attitude rather than network equations, and offer this pseudo-answer comparing a strict PI-type bandpass with OP's bastardized "in-between" filter.
I have compared two filters, one a strict PI-type constant-k, and the other, OP's "in-between" filter. The inductor L1 defines the difference between these two types. It mostly affects the bandpass roll-off of the upper cut-off frequency, and the stop-band slope of frequencies above cut-off. Inductor L1 makes upper cut-off frequency have the same "Q" as lower cut-off frequency. Stop-band at upper frequency end matches that of stop-band at lower frequency end:
I would agree with OP that the two arms not included in this simulation are tweaks to adjust the filter's response, perhaps to account for other component tolerances. But what filter parameters these arms are meant to compensate are not stated.

Perhaps it is important to OP's application that stop-band slopes match? However, note that pass-band is slightly asymmetric. Could pass-band be more important than stop-band? If so, a fully symmetric filter (shown below) might be considered. While upper stop-band doesn't match lower stop-band, the pass-band looks to be better:


This question generated many comments, and several close votes, and I think the resolution is that the transfer function is irrelevant -- you are stuck on it as a means to an end, and just aren't aware that a simpler solution exists.
To summarize: you ask two different questions: how to rescale a filter, and how to plot its transfer function.  With hints of a third, how to derive it symbolically; which, indeed, going the symbolic route is... painful, to say the least; algebraically manipulating networks of more than a few components is not trivial.  This explains the close votes.
As it turns out, the transfer function is irrelevant for one transformation.
We obtain the same transfer function, rescaled to a different frequency \$\omega \rightarrow \omega^\prime\$, by changing L and C proportional to \$\frac{\omega}{\omega^\prime}\$.  R and Zo remain constant, because the \$\sqrt{\frac{L}{C}}\$ ratio is not changing in the process.
If the initial center frequency was, say, 10MHz, and you desire it for 2MHz, then increase L and C by 10/2 = 5 times, each.  Since \$\omega\$ goes as \$\frac{1}{\sqrt{LC}}\$, increasing them by 5x each decreases \$\omega\$ by 5x, and we are done.
For example, filter prototypes are often given in tables, normalized to \$\omega = 1\$ and \$Z_0 = 1\$, and you scale L*C and L/C proportionally, respectively, to obtain a desired filter design.
For a bandpass, this changes both LF and HF cutoffs proportionally.
There are other transformations if you need to change the bandpass width, or LF/HF cutoffs, but at that point you will need to identify the filter prototype, and an analytical solution based on component values becomes much more difficult. (I don't happen to remember the transformation, offhand, myself.)
It's not clear if such a transformation is what you had desired here -- but it's also not clear that such a transformation is meaningful or [exactly] possible for the network shown.  In particular, the zero network(s): should they be attached to the LF or HF cutoff? Or somewhere inbetween?  If inbetween, how should they be scaled?  Is it actually K-derived?  (Does anyone actually design K-derived filters these days?)
But this is also the point where your question becomes peculiar: as you have seen from your own experience, filters aren't easy to analyze and manipulate, and starting with an example, then wanting to change it by broad strokes, kind of brings into question what you wanted with it in the first place.  And -- if you knew what you wanted from it -- why are you asking about the transfer function, surely that means you already knew something important about it?  In the future, make clear what it is you are doing, and include background information where possible.  For example, if this is a homework problem (as one comment hinted), show the full problem statement, what you know about it, and where you are stuck on it.
Finally -- if you know it's basically a bandpass filter, surely it would be simpler to start with a defined prototype (e.g. normalized bandpass), and use a standard calculator?  e.g.: 
https://markimicrowave.com/technical-resources/tools/lc-filter-design-tool/ 
which also gets you the other design information necessary to use the network (e.g. stopband attenuation needed to place other signals/bands/images in the system), no need to reverse-engineer a network.
